# ion-datetime Ionic 3 show initial value

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am using ion-datetime for my project

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/

It is working nice, only problem i have to show inital value, that does not show??

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="YYYY" name="LastServiceDate" value="2017"></ion-datetime>
```

I put value inside attibute it does not show inital?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no value property in ion-datetime in documentation, try ngModel.

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="YYYY" name="LastServiceDate" [(ngModel)]="dateValueVar">
</ion-datetime>
```